# How do you add command line options to flycheck's C++ checker?

Tags: flycheck, c++, clang

I needed to specify stdlib options in a certain environment, so I changed the flycheck executable to `clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`, which is needed to compile the file.

However, I got the error `Error while checking syntax automatically: (error "Output file descriptor of flycheck-c/c++-clang is closed")` after doing so, and searches don't turn anything up.

How do I help flycheck out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't change the executable, but rather modify [flycheck's variables that get translated into a command](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/languages.html#c-c). In your case, you have to change them like:

```
(setq flycheck-clang-language-standard "c++11")
(setq flycheck-clang-standard-library "libc++")
```

You can also customize these variables (by running `M-x customize-variable`)